# How to use css to display an avatar pic with details next to it?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, html

i have this part of html in my view:

```
 <div class="info">    
   <img width="52" height="52" alt="Avatar" src="/ThemeFiles/Base/images/User/user-avatar.png"/> 
 </div>
 <ul class="links">
    <li>
       <%: newsItem.CommentDate %>
    </li>
    <li>
       <%: ViewBag.UserName %>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

i have my avatar showing with the newsItem.CommentDate  and ViewBag.UserName **underneath** the avatar. How can i get the date and username to display NEXT TO the avatar??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
div.info { display: inline-block; width:52px; height:52px; }
ul.links { display: inline-block; }
```

You might have to do some tweaking, though, if you want them to line-up in a certain way (one way being to give `ul.links` a fixed `height`, along with some `padding-top`.

You can also use `float: left` in place of `display:inline-block` for browsers that don't understand it.

With `float`s, though, you then have to consider what happens to elements *following* them - with `inline-block` elements you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Try floating the avatar div to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making it two divs and then using `float: left` on the first div

```
  <div class="info">    
     <img width="52" height="52" alt="Avatar" src="/ThemeFiles/Base/images/User/user-avatar.png"/> 
  </div>

   <div class="linkscontainer">
          <ul class="links">
            <li>
               <%: newsItem.CommentDate %>
            </li>
            <li>
               <%: ViewBag.UserName %>
            </li>
          </ul> 
      <div>
```